How to use Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.ExistsAsync()?
Environment is .NET 6 and Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.20.0
Given:
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString: blobConnection, blobContainerName: blobContainer);
BlobClient? blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName: myBlobName);
using (MemoryStream? ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     await blob.DownloadToAsync(destination: ms); //no problem here
}
bool exists = await blob.ExistsAsync(); //exception thrown here 

I can confirm that myBlobName is a valid path because I can call blob.DownloadToAsync() and it works as expected. However, with the same BlobClient object I call await blob.ExistsAsync() and it throws an exception that says the path has invalid characters.
Is my use of this function wrong or could there be another issue?
Originally, I called ExistsAsync before DownloadToAsync but I noticed it threw exceptions even when I KNEW the blob existed. I've also tried using two different instances of BlobClient with the same path but I got the same result.

What's the name of the blob?

@GauravMantri all my blob names follow the convention:
blobContainer + "/" + module + "/" + date.Year + "/" + date.Month.ToString(format: "#00") + "/" + id.ToString() + ".pdf";
this one in specific is "Maury/Land/2024/05/24005356.pdf". It does exist and I can download it but I cant call ExistsAsync() on it or any other blobs...

What exception do you get?


However, with the same BlobClient object I call await blob.ExistsAsync() and it throws an exception that says the path has invalid characters.

The issue in not with blob.ExistsAsync()  function, It may be invalid path or names or characters provided in the blob parameters.
In my environment, I have folder structure like below which stored some files.
Portal:

Now, when I tried with correct parameters in code it executed successfully.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;


namespace BlobExistsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string blobConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat32612;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string blobContainer = "maury";
            string myBlobName = "Land/2024/05/24005356.pdf";

            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString: blobConnection, blobContainerName: blobContainer);
            BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName: myBlobName);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await blob.DownloadToAsync(destination: ms);
            }

            bool exists = await blob.ExistsAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob '{blob.Name}' exists: {exists}");
        }
    }
}

The above executed and downloads the blob to a MemoryStream and then check if the blob exists using the ExistsAsync method.
Output:
Blob 'Land/2024/05/24005356.pdf' exists: True


Reference:
You can refer this MS-Document to know about Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata of Azure Blob Storage.
